# debugging with gdb: why this=0x0?

Tags: gdb

I'm using gdb for debugging a program. And what I see is kind of strange:

```
(gdb) bt

0xb59656f8 in globalCallStubClass::addCallContext (**this=0x0**)
    at /ccase_enodeb/callp/build_callp/src/test/framework/shared/src/shared_call_context.cc:1962

0xb5b52e64 in rrcStubClass::process_scenario_spontaneous_trigger_RRC_CONNECTION_REQUEST (gcppMsgCtx=...)
    at /ccase_enodeb/callp/build_callp/src/test/framework/rrc/src/rrc_connection_request.cc:90

0xb6c3be4c in Gcpp::routeMessage (this=0xb392e9d0) at /ccase_enodeb/callp/build_callp/src/callp_services/gcpp/src/gcpp.cc:1095

0xb6c3b3b0 in Gcpp::loop (this=0xb392e9d0, Default_Method_Ptr=0)
    at /ccase_enodeb/callp/build_callp/src/callp_services/gcpp/src/gcpp.cc:925

0xb58d2ae0 in stubBthdEntryPoint () at /ccase_enodeb/callp/build_callp/src/test/framework/root/src/stub_root.cc:314

0x000191f8 in lxb_thd_entry (pCtx=0x68c0f8) at /vobs/onepltf/ltefdd/core/src/lxbase/lxbase.c:3289

0xb575602e in start_thread () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libpthread.so.0

0xb56d6ab8 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc.so.6

0xb56d6ab8 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc.so.6
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

(gdb) print pCallStub
$1 = (globalCallStubClass *) **0x7a1da8**

(gdb) print this
$2 = (globalCallStubClass * const) **0x0**
```

The chrash appears at line marked with (-->):

```
if (pCallStub != NULL) {

-->callStubClass* pCallInst =  pCallStub->addCallContext();

}
```

Function `addCallContext` is called for object `pCallStub` (`pCallStub` is instantiated and is not `NULL`). When I print `pCallStub` I can see that it has an address:

```
(gdb) print pCallStub
    $1 = (globalCallStubClass *) 0x7a1da8
```

but still, `this` (which should be `pCallStub`) is `0x0`:

```
(gdb) print this
    $2 = (globalCallStubClass * const) 0x0
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks,
Geta

Answer (score 0):

`pCallStub` is `0x0`, so it's pointing to `NULL`. You have to instantiate an object with `pCallStub = new globalCallStubClass()` or a creator function like `pCallStub = createGlobalCallStubClass()` before using the pointer.

Comment: But, this is the problem, pCallStub is instantiated and is not NULL:  (gdb) print pCallStub
$1 = (globalCallStubClass *) 0x1b61720

Comment: How is `pCallStub` instantiated? Is it instantiated in a different thread?

Comment: Yes, it is instantiated in a different thread like this: pCallStub = new globalCallStubClass(MAX_UE_PER_CALLP_PROCESS, UE_CTX_VALIDITY_BITS); But at the moment when I want to call the method, the object is already instantiated

Comment: It seems to be a syncronization issue: when you use `pCallStub->addCallContext();` in the second thread, pCallStub does not have the right value. Try adding `volatile` to `pCallStub` and compile without any optimization.

Answer (score 0):

```
(gdb) print pCallStub
$1 = (globalCallStubClass *) **0x7a1da8**

(gdb) print this
$2 = (globalCallStubClass * const) **0x0**
```

You need to show more code for us to understand your issue.
There is no context here where we could see where this == pCallStub
Also, if you have optimizations turned on, you might not see what you think you're seeing (like the compiler optimized the function call and the stack so gdb doesn't report the right variable because it search it on the stack. Typically, on a x86 system, you'll find "this" in ecx register.

Since you have multiple thread you can have the "multithread singleton issue", that is, one thread is allocating and storing in the singleton instance, but other thread don't see it yet.

Try to use atomic compare and swap to set the singleton instance for example.