# what does it mean when an object in gdb says 0x0?

Tags: c++, gdb, cython

I'm printing a variable in gdb and it shows:

```
(gdb) p __pyx_v_doc
$27 = (__pyx_obj_5spacy_6tokens_3doc_Doc *) 0x0
```

0x0 is hex 0. Does this mean the object is empty? How do I see what's inside? Thank you.

Comment: Just a null pointer? Pointers do not have an "inside". Your pointer is zero. That's all there is.

Comment: 0x0 is the null pointer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645857/debugging-with-gdb-why-this-0x0

Comment: Use p/d to print a decimal zero.

Comment: @JackPeng If your question was adequately answered you can mark this question as resolved by clicking the check mark next to the answer you found most useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0x0` refers the the address at `0` a.k.a `NULL`.

This means there is no object at that location and trying to access anything at that address will likely result in a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).